# Fade to Black Transition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, transition, react-navigation-stack

Is there anyway to have a React Native navigation transition by fading to black, then fade out from black to the next screen?

Have been googling for awhile, I have only found methods of changing the screens opacity, or moving it from left to right or right to left, But I haven't found a transition from a screen to black. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could have a full screen `Animated.View` with absolute positioning and `backgroundColor: 'black'` on your component, starting at `opacity: 0`. Then when the user presses a button to navigate you animate to opacity to 1, and your callback upon completing the animation is to navigate to the next screen. Your next screen starts with the same component but opacity: 1, and your `componentDidMount` animates opacity to 0. I think that should work...

Comment: Elements on the screen could still be seen, say a blue <Button>, would still be present though the animation. no?

Comment: Even if you set a high `zIndex`? An alternative would be to do the reverse, and have a black full-screen view sit behind everything else, i.e. lower zIndex than the main view, and then fade the main view to `opacity: 0`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest version of `react-navigation-stack`, you can use `CardAnimationContext`/`useCardAnimation` to achieve this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Animated, Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  CardStyleInterpolators,
  HeaderStyleInterpolators,
  useCardAnimation,
} from 'react-navigation-stack';

function ScreenA({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.push('ScreenB')} title="Go to B" />
    </View>
  );
}

function ScreenB() {
  const { current } = useCardAnimation();

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
          { backgroundColor: 'black', opacity: current.progress },
        ]}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator({
  ScreenA,
  ScreenB,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place a black `<div>` behind that screen and

Thanks @Prajwal, CSS transition solution:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName(`main`)[0].style.opacity = `0`;
```

```css
  main {
    position: fixed; /* place it before .black */
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition-property: opacity; /* set opacity to one of the transition properties */
    transition-duration: 4s; /* set transition duration */
  }

  .black {
    position: fixed; /* place it behind main */
    background-color: black; /* make it black */
    width: 100%; /* make it fill available space */
    height: 100%; /* make it fill available space*/
  }

  body {
    margin: 0; /* make it fill available space*/
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="black"></div>
<main>
  <p>lorem</p>
</main>
</body>
```

You can also use the [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function to lower the opacity bit by bit.

```js
  const step = 0.05; // set the step of opacity change
  const timeInterval = 200; // set the sleep time of opacity change
  const times = 1 / step; // calculate times needed for opacity change
  document.getElementsByTagName(`main`)[0].style.opacity = `1`; // set initial opacity to make getting the float value of it work.
  let time = 0; // initially, the time of making changes is zero
  const lowerOpacity = window.setInterval(function() {
      if (time + 1 === times) {
        window.clearInterval(lowerOpacity);
      } // clearInterval() when the time of changes has reached the needed times
      document.getElementsByTagName(`main`)[0].style.opacity =
        `${parseFloat(document.getElementsByTagName(`main`)[0].style.opacity) -
        0.05}`; // set the opacity to make it dimmer
      time += 1; // increment time to match the changed times
    }
    , timeInterval);
```

```css
  main {
    position: fixed; /* place it before .black */
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .black {
    position: fixed; /* place it behind main */
    background-color: black; /* make it black */
    width: 100%; /* make it fill available space */
    height: 100%; /* make it fill available space*/
  }

  body {
    margin: 0; /* make it fill available space*/
  }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="black"></div>
<main>
  <p>lorem</p>
</main>
</body>
```

Comment: Or use CSS transitions. Which does the same, costs less.

Comment: @Prajwal Thanks, haven't thought about that. Will update my answer.

Comment: OP wants to know how to do this in React Native :)

Comment: @VilleKoo I believe it's just the same. Maybe it would need a few tweaks, but OP would be fine with this. :)

Comment: No it's not since React Native is not really working with the DOM.

Comment: React Native is different, maybe with Animation API or something ?

Comment: @VilleKoo Sorry for the delay. I had no experience with react and thought it would only need minor adjustments. Again, sorry for your time. I think the idea still applies here though, so I'm hesitating to delete this answer. Should I delete it?

Comment: I don't think you should delete it, your answer will still help someone working with React :)

Comment: @VilleKoo Thanks, I'll keep it here.